# The Algorithm Design Manual - Working with the Big Oh

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

I'm reading *The Algorithm Design Manuel* and one part is kind of confusing to me

The part that's confusing to me is how in the "Proving the Theta" section he proves that selection sort is Ω(n^2).
I mean, I understand that for some (c) c.n^2 can be a lower bound for selection sort, however I don't understand how he proves this in that section.

I would really appreciate it if you could help me understand that part.
Thanks.
.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to avoid what is repeating what is in the text, but you have exactly:

$T(n) = (n-1)+(n-2)+\ldots+1+0 =n\tfrac{n-1}{2} = \tfrac12n^2 -\tfrac12n$

and as an upper bound taking each value *up* to $n-1$:

$T(n) \le (n-1)+(n-1)+\ldots+(n-1)+(n-1) =n(n-1) = n^2-n$

and as an lower bound taking values of at least $\tfrac n2$ *down* to $\tfrac n2$ and other *down* to $0$ $($assuming $n$ is even; the odd case gives $\tfrac14n^2+\tfrac14 n)$:

$T(n) \ge \tfrac n2 +\ldots +\tfrac n2 +0+\ldots +0 = \tfrac n2 \times \tfrac n2 +\tfrac n2 \times 0 = \tfrac14n^2$

Since all three are essentially of the order of $n^2$ up to a constant, you can conclude $T(n)$ is $O(n^2)$ and $\Omega(n^2)$ and so $\Theta(n^2)$

Comment: Thanks, really helped a lot :).